# Retrieving Keys from JSON Array key-value pair dynamically - Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a question that would like to seek your expertise on.

This is a JSON array that I have:

```
[{"A":20,"B":32,"C":27,"D":30,"E":40}]
```

What I would like to do is to retrieve the keys (A, B, C, D, E) from the JSON array instead of the values. I am able to retrieve the values but not the keys.

I am using this to retrieve the values dynamically:

```
function calculateSum(jsonArray) {
    var result = 0;
    for (var i = jsonArray.length - 1;  i >= 0; --i)
    {
        var o = jsonArray[i];
        A = o.A;
        B = o.B;
        C = o.C;
        D = o.D;
        E = o.E;
        result = A + B + C + D + E;
        return result;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Similarly, what should I do to retrieve the **keys** using JavaScript?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Are you using [D3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3) as your tag implies? Because in that case, you can just use `d3.keys()`:

```
var data = [{"A":20,"B":32,"C":27,"D":30,"E":40}];
d3.keys(data[0]); // ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

If you want the sum of all the values, you might be better off using `d3.values()` and `d3.sum()`:

```
var data = [{"A":20,"B":32,"C":27,"D":30,"E":40}, {"F":50}];
// get total of all object totals
var total = d3.sum(data, function(d) {
    // get total of a single object's values
    return d3.sum(d3.values(d));
});
total; // 199
```

Answer (score 11):

All of the current posted solutions have a problem. None of them check for [`object.hasOwnProperty(prop)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) while iterating over an object using a for...in loop. This might cause phantom keys to appear if properties are added to the prototype.

Quoting [Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)

> Be aware that members that are added to the prototype of the object will be included in the enumeration. It is wise to program defensively by using the hasOwnProperty method to distinguish the true members of the object.

Adding a check for `hasOwnProperty`  to maerics' excellent solution.

```
var getKeys = function (arr) {
        var key, keys = [];
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (key in arr[i]) {
                if (arr[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    keys.push(key);
                }
            }
        }
        return keys;
    };
```

Comment: +1 This is not really a problem for a JSON-deserialized object, but you're right, the code is better with the check. I'll add it to my answer...

Answer (score 4):

Use `for .. in`:

```
var result = 0;

for (var i = jsonArray.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    var o = jsonArray[i];
    for (var key in o) {
      if (o.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        result += o[key];
      }
    }
    // in your code, you return result here, 
    // which might not give the right result 
    // if the array has more than 1 element
}

return result;
```

Comment: This just sums up the values. I believe @Queryer wants to retrieve the list of keys.

Comment: @Sahil Muthoo: That's not what I understood.... To me he wants to sum up the values, but without knowing the keys beforehand....

Answer (score 4):

```
var easy = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
}

var keys = [], vals = []
for (var key in easy) {
    keys.push(key)
    vals.push(easy[key])
}

alert(keys+" - tha's how easy baby, it's gonna be")
alert(vals+" - tha's how easy baby, it's gonna be")
```

---

### defensively

Including @Sahil's defensive method...

```
for (var key in easy) {
    if (easy.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        keys.push(key)
        vals.push(easy[key])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [JavaScript `for..in` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```
var getKeys = function(arr) {
  var key, keys = [];
  for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    for (key in arr[i]) {
      keys.push(key);
    }
  }
  return keys;
};

var a = [{"A":20, "B":32, "C":27, "D":30, "E":40}, {"F":50}]
getKeys(a); // => ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the simplest.

```
var a = [{"A":20,"B":32,"C":27,"D":30,"E":40}];
Object.keys( a[0] );
```

Result :

```
["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

Comment: What if there are multiple objects in the array?

Answer (score 0):

A `for-in`-loop does the trick. On one object it looks like this:

```
var o = {
    a: 5,
    b: 3
};
var num = 0;

for (var key in o) {
    num += o[key];
}
alert(num);
```

Comment: This just sums up the values. I believe @Queryer wants to retrieve the list of keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It is simple:

```
var a = [{"A":20,"B":32,"C":27,"D":30,"E":40}];

for(var i in a){
  for(var j in a[i]){
    console.log(j); // shows key
    console.log(a[i][j]); // shows value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be parsed recursively like below

```
var getKeys = function(previousKeys,obj){
        var currentKeys = Object.keys(obj);
        previousKeys = previousKeys.concat(currentKeys);
        for(var i=0;i<currentKeys.length;i++){
            var innerObj = obj[currentKeys[i]];
            if(innerObj!==null && typeof innerObj === 'object' && !Array.isArray(innerObj)){
            return this.getKeys(previousKeys,innerObj);
            }
        }
        return previousKeys;
    }
```

usage: `getKeys([],{"a":"1",n:{c:"3",e:{ f:4,g:[1,2,3]}}})`

Result:
["a", "n", "c", "e", "f", "g"]

Answer (score 0):

```
var _ = require('underscore');

var obj = [{"A":20,"B":32,"C":27,"D":30,"E":40},{"F":50}, {"G":60,"H":70},{"I":80}];

var keys = [], values = [];



_.each(obj, function(d) {

     keys.push(_.keys(d));

     values.push(_.values(d));
});


// Keys   ->  [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I' ]
console.log('Keys   -> ', _.flatten(keys ));
// Values ->  [ 20, 32, 27, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 ]
console.log('Values -> ', _.flatten(values));
```

Answer (score 0):

**stop reinventing the wheel** !

```
Object.keys()
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)