# How to get Json String without set data in getString("name")?

Tags: android, json

Im doing a dynamic form to Android and I need just read a Json file and build a form and it should work in anyway. How can I do it? In "name" getString("name") what I can put there to get a name without write "name" inside de method?

Comment: Can you include a sample of your code?

Comment: I just need to get a String without to write strings name. eg: getString("name") -> getString( the index of JsonObject)

Comment: I guess you could get the index of the key- if you went through the step of getting all keys into an array. But that seems laborious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the question that you want to find the keys of a JSONArray? Iterate through the array, grab the key of each object. Then, grab the value.

See second answer: [Retrieving Keys from JSON Array key-value pair dynamically - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391362/retrieving-keys-from-json-array-key-value-pair-dynamically-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should help:

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys()

You can use this Iterator to iterate through all the keys and then use the key to extract the desired values.

Additionally, if dealing with a JSONArray you could use the following too:
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#names()