# How do I "filter" or otherwise restructure this data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have some data of the form:

```
var Input = {
"Variable": "Variable Name",
  "Data": {
    "key_1": value_1,
    "key_2": value_2,
    "key_3": value_3,
    "key_4": value_4,
    "key_5": value_5,
  },
"Omega": value
};
```

What I'd like to do is refactor it to this form:

```
var Output = [
{
    "variable":"variable name",
    values:[
          {
              "label":"key_1",
              "value": value_1
          },
          {
              "label":"key_2",
              "value": value_2
          },
          {
              "label":"key_1",
              "value": value_1
          },
          {
              "label":"key_3",
              "value": value_3
          },
          {
              "label":"key_4",
              "value": value_4
          },
          {
              "label":"key_5",
              "value": value_5
          },
    ]
```

I went through and found what I needed from the Input data by looping through it and pushing the relevant key/value pairs to an output array. But, that just gives me an array of values.

I could (although I haven't tried this yet) loop through the array and push the even indices to "label" and odd to "value". I may end up doing that, but if there is a more sensible way, such as structuring the output array in the form I am after, then I'd rather do that.

What I am trying to do, ultimately, is generate a bar graph in D3.js or NVD3.js that has the keys as labels and values as the height of the bar.

However, I am new to d3.js and, so far, I can't generate anything using the data in the format I was given

Thoughts? Thanks in advance.

[edited: the JSON that wasn't.]

Comment: Does the order of the items in your values array matter?

Comment: what do you do with `Omega`? include or exclude from output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving Keys from JSON Array key-value pair dynamically - Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391362/retrieving-keys-from-json-array-key-value-pair-dynamically-javascript)

Comment: D3.js has appropriate method: [`d3.entries`](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_entries), though it returns data in slightly different format (`{key, value}`, not `{label, value}`).

Comment: Omega could be included in another graph of other data within the json.

Comment: Just to be precise: There is no JSON in your entire question. Both, `Input` as well as `Output` are declared using an object literal. Have a look at [*"What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?"*](/q/2904131) for the differences.

Comment: @altocumulus Correct. It's a mess to get it from the pickled pandas dataframe to something that d3.js might be able to consume.

Answer (score 2):

I modified your input object slightly to have valid syntax.  You can loop through the keys of `Input.Data` in order to fill the `output.values` array.

```
var input = {
"Variable": "Variable Name",
  "Data": {
    "key_1": 1,
    "key_2": 2,
    "key_3": 3,
    "key_4": 4,
    "key_5": 5,
  },
"Omega": 'ohm'
};

var output = {};
output.variable = input.Variable;
output.values = [];

for (var name in input.Data) {
  if (!input.Data.hasOwnProperty(name)) continue;
  output.values.push({label: name, value: input.Data[name]});
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this:

```
var Input = {
"Variable": "Variable Name",
  "Data": {
    "key_1": 1,
    "key_2": 2,
    "key_3": 3,
    "key_4": 4,
    "key_5": 5,
  },
"Omega": 6
};

Input.values = Object.keys(Input.Data).map(function(item){ return { "label": item, "value": Input.Data[item] } });
delete Input.Data;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop over the keys and return a new object with the wanted content.

```js
var input = {
        "Variable": "Variable Name",
        "Data": {
            "key_1": 'value_1',
            "key_2": 'value_2',
            "key_3": 'value_3',
            "key_4": 'value_4',
            "key_5": 'value_5',
        },
        "Omega": 'value'
    },
    output = {
        "Variable": "Variable Name",
        values: Object.keys(input.Data).map(function (k) {
            var o = {};
            o[k] = input.Data[k];
            return o;
        })
    };
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(output, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little cryptic yet fully functional.

```js
var Input = {
"Variable": "Variable Name",
  "Data": {
    "key_1": "value_1",
    "key_2": "value_2",
    "key_3": "value_3",
    "key_4": "value_4",
    "key_5": "value_5",
  },
"Omega": "value"
},

  Output = [Object.keys(Input).reduce((p,c) => {c == "Variable" ? p[c] = Input[c]
                                                                : c == "Data" &&
                                                                  (p.Values = Object.keys(Input[c])
                                                                                    .reduce((a,k) => a.concat({label : k, value : Input[c][k]}),[]));
                                                return p;},{})];
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(Output,null,2) + "</pre>");
```

Comment: Cryptic is right ... it would work though if "values" wasn't in quotes in the output. I'm trying to fix that now. If you have suggestions, please toss them my way.

Comment: Values is just the key. Does it really matter if it's in quotes or not..? You can access it like `Output[0].Values`

Answer (score -1):

Since `data` is an `Object` you can get the keys collection using `Object.keys(data)`, then you can get each key's value by using `data[key]`. Incorporate this into a `forEach` and you can do anything you like.